# How to save an Array of values in "Keychain"

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

How to save an Array of values i.e. string values in "Keychain" and access those values as a list.
I am able to save a single value in a String and access it, but difficult in case of array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save array in Keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182838/save-array-in-keychain)

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the string array to JSON and save it. Deserialize it after reading from keychain.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you encode them to base64. Either use `Codable` or `JSONSerialization`. Since you have an array of strings (and not custom objects) I suggest JSON. Something like the following should do:

```
func stringFromArray(_ array: [String]) -> String? {
    return (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: []))?.base64EncodedString()
}
func arrayFromString(_ string: String) -> [String]? {
    guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: string) else {
        return nil
    }
    return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String]
}
```

Comment: i have save string value in an array and multiple times repeat this process.
should i encode the "array" to json and save in key chain?
and then i have to access that arrray again.

Comment: @Ankush_ios_2017 Please rephrase your question.

Comment: thanks @matic
it was done by serialization and deserialization, as you suggested